# Solvability and representation of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group, and let $G=G^{(0)}\unrhd G^{(1)}\unrhd...G^{(n)}=1$ be its derived series. Is it true that any irreducible representation of $G$ has dimension at most $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finite Heisenberg group $H_n(q)$ has $q-1$ irreducible representations of dimension $q^n$ (and $q^{2n}$ irreducible representations of dimension $1$), but its derived series just has length $2$.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample.